# Modifying directory security takes long for large folder

Tags: c#, acl

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application that manages the security for folders.
When I want to add or remove a user from a specific folder, it takes too long (after 5 minutes I stop the execution).
This specific folder in question is 50GB big, has 11,389 files and 470 folders.
This is a folder shared on our network.

This is the code

```cs
public void Remove(UserPrincipal user)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(_folderPath))
    {
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(_folderPath);
        var rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(user.Sid.ToString()), FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow);
        bool isModified;
        dSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.RemoveAll,rule, out isModified);
        if(isModified)
            Directory.SetAccessControl(_folderPath, dSecurity);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can make it faster? Or use another libary?

Answer (score 0):

sounds more like a design flaw. Adding/removing access to a folder recursively means apply to EVERY file/folder the permissions, it sounds fair it takes long. My suggestion is to create AD groups per role, and ADD/REMOVE the users from that role who has the required access.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the security must be set at different levels of the folder. In this specific case the max depth is 5. Someone can have access to the top-most folder or someone can have access to the bottom folder. We already tried using AD and hit the limit of 1000 AD groups a user can have.
I thought that if I just modified the access at root level, inheritance would do its jobs so the code won't have to recursively go to each folder